# scala: serializable alternatives to java.lang.reflect.Field

Tags: scala, serialization, reflection, apache-spark, case-class

Suppose `User` is a case class that holds information about a user:

```
case class User(name: String, age: Int)
```

given a field name (e.g. `"name"` or `"age"`), I want to return a *function* that  extract this field (without parsing the field name again). In short, I needed this to work:

```
val u = User(name = "john",age = 44)
val func = extractFunctionFromFieldName("name") // returns func: User => Any
func(u) // return "john"
```

Reading about reflection, I got something like this to work:

```
def extractFunctionFromFieldName(s: String): User => Any = {
  val f = classOf[User].getDeclaredField(s)
  f.setAccessible(true)
  u: User => f.get(u)
}
```

The problem is that this function is not serializable since `java.lang.reflect.Field` is not serializable.

Any suggestions or alternatives?

Notes / more background:

- The list of fields is much larger than just `{name,age}` and is constantly growing. That's why I want to avoid hard-coding
- Using `productElement` should work without serialization issues since fields are replaced with numbers. But I understand there are no guarantees on the order of the product elements.
- BTW, I need it to be serializable since I am using this with apache spark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Using productElement should work without serialization issues since fields are replaced with numbers. But I understand there are no guarantees on the order of the product elements.

There are. For case class they will be in the same order as the parameters.

Alternately you can make a class, which can still be a function (a bit more general here; if this is not needed, change to work with `User` only should be easy):

```
case class ExtractField[T](s: String)(implicit t: ClassTag[T]) extends (T => Any) {
  @transient lazy val f = {
    val f = t.runtimeClass.getDeclaredField(s)
    f.setAccessible(true)
    f
  }

  def apply(x: T) = f.get(x)
}
```

This will initialize the field only the first time it's applied, and so can be applied many times after deserializing it once without repeating `getDeclaredField` calls.

I didn't notice initially that this was already required by the question, so the other solution I gave initially is inapplicable: you can just move `f` inside the function (in your case `f` is already known when you create the function object and "captured" by it, which is why it has to be serialized):

```
def extractFunctionFromFieldName(s: String): User => Any = { u: User => 
  val f = classOf[User].getDeclaredField(s)
  f.setAccessible(true)
  f.get(u)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But as I stated in the question - I would like the function to avoid the need to parse the string containing the field name again every time the function is called. Imagine the function is generated once, but applied a billion times.

Comment: This is precisely why I gave the last solution. It will create `f` only in the constructor, i.e. in your case on deserialization.

Comment: You should also consider the `productElement` solution, which won't involve reflection at all.

Comment: @Amir I fixed the solution a bit, now it should actually work.

Comment: The fact that makes your last `extractFunctionFromFieldName` serializable is the fact that you marked `f` as transient. But for the same reason you can't use the object after being deserialized since `f` does not have its value anymore.

Comment: It's a lazy val, so it should be reinitialized correctly starting with Scala 2.9 http://stackoverflow.com/a/4773511/9204. If it doesn't work, please report the bug to Scala team (and make it a `var` and set in `readObject` as a workaround).

Comment: What _didn't_ work is that `setAccessible` wasn't called, because it was part of the constructor; after this edit it's part of `f`'s initializer.

Comment: Got it! it worked. Thanks. It's actually very clever (the combination of `transient` and `lazy`).
 
one tiny edit -  to make it compile I had to add parentheses around  `(T => Any)`.

Comment: Happy to have helped, a bit sorry it took me 3 tries to get it right :) I basically don't use Java serialization unless I have no other choice.

Comment: What would you use instead here?

Comment: Kryo, since we are talking about Spark http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/tuning.html#data-serialization